# reload/reset route file in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.3

This is a rare question. Could be there is thousand better ways to solve the next problem but I didn't discover how to do it better.

I have a site in N languages (en, fr, es). In each request I set the locale. In the routing file I have something like

```
Route::get(trans('url.home'), 'User\HomeController@index');
```

I request the URL **/user** and works properly.

In the other hand, I'm implementing the alternate meta-tag

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="http://es.url.com/usuario" />
```

and in a Trait I tried to do something like

```
App::setLocale($new_locale);
$alternate[$new_locale] = action('User\HomeController@index');
```

The locale changed properly (I used the method Trans and the message was translated properly) but not the route action. The question is, are there any way to "reload/reset" the routes?

Just a clue or another point of view will be enought for me :)

Thanks and sorry for my english.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm facing the same situation on the moment..

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the best thing to do, but you can do it! (At least in Laravel 8)

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::middleware('web')->group(base_path('routes/other_routes.php'));
Route::getRoutes()->refreshNameLookups();
Route::getRoutes()->refreshActionLookups();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a delicate question, and I may be wrong, but this Laracast may be able to help:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/multi-language-routes-and-url

Comment: thanks for your response. In that solution, the localization is placed in the path (domain.com/en/some-url). In the other hand I'm using the same route but different subdomain (en.domain.com/user es.domain.com/usuario). I'll looking more deeply in your link. Thanks a lot!